# Open source expert system

Tags: open-source, expert-system

does anyone know about a open source expert system? actually, I'm rather interested in calling its inferential engine from C#.

Answer (score 4):

Both CLIPS and JESS are already mentioned in other answers, so I will supply this link to CLIPS versus JESS:
http://www.comp.lancs.ac.uk/~kristof/research/notes/clipsvsjess/

It was written June 4, 1999, and at that time the advantage was clearly with CLIPS.

If you don't want to read it all, here are the conclusions:

> Chapter 3 The conclusions
>
> Both CLIPS and JESS are products with a large support on the internet,
>   but CLIPS seems to have a broader audience, probably because it exists
>   longer. This difference in age results in the CLIPS package being more
>   stable and complete, while JESS users will still experience some minor
>   bugs. JESS is constantly updated and the author, Ernest Friedman-Hill,
>   has been very responsive to user/developer feedback and regularly puts
>   out new releases and bug fixes.
>
> Nowadays, the choice between JESS and CLIPS depends on the
>   application. If it is web-based or should reside in applet-form, the
>   choice of JESS is a very logical one (which is even supported by the
>   authors of CLIPS). For the more classic applications, CLIPS will
>   probably be chosen because of its reputation of being more stable and
>   having more support.
>
> The future of JESS depends highly on the evolution of the web, the
>   Java programming language and its own future stability. These three
>   conditions make that there is a great possibility that JESS will
>   become more popular and more frequently used. Especially the
>   object-oriented possibilities and the easy integration into Java code
>   makes JESS’ future very promising.
>
> CLIPS, on the other hand, is more likely to implement the new and
>   sophisticated features first as they come out, since it still has the
>   advantage in time. CLIPS has also various extensions and variants(like
>   FuzzyCLIPS, AGENT CLIPS, DYNACLIPS, KnowExec, CAPE, PerlCLIPS, wxCLIPS
>   and EHSIS to name a few) that give it an advantage with respect to
>   support of methods like fuzzy logic and agents.
>
> The multifunctional developing environment of CLIPS for operating
>   systems that support windows is also an advantage, while JESS has just
>   one window with two buttons (‘clear window’ and ‘quit’), without a
>   menu. Figures 1 and 2 depict both environments.
>
> To summarize, CLIPS is still more complete and stable than JESS, but
>   this might change in the future, since the JESS package is being
>   improved constantly. Besides that, JESS has also the property of using
>   Java, which in the long run might prove to be a big advantage over
>   CLIPS.

These links may also be of interest:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS

Commercial & Freeware Expert System Shells
http://www.kbsc.com/rulebase.html

[Are there open source expert systems with reasoning capabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642004/are-there-open-source-expert-systems-with-reasoning-capabilities)

Answer (score 3):

I went through the same process, about a year ago, trying to find a good .Net system for this. I recall finding a few decent engines, but they were all too general, and required too many assumptions.

In the end I found that writing my own system was pretty easy to do, and it did exactly what I wanted it to, without any extra bull to make it work with some abstract generalized engine.

It might help to know what your intended use is.

Comment: Can you disclose it ? I mean your inference engine's source code.

Comment: Unfortunately no... but really my engine was very specific to my use case and probably couldn't be reused. It wasn't generalized, which was the point of my response. Instead of using a generalized framework it's often easier to figure out exactly what you need your system to do and roll some code for it. Depends on how complex your requirements are.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/) -- it is coded in C.

There's more info on CLIPS at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS).

Answer (score 1):

If you'd consider a rule-processing engine, JBoss Rules (also known as Drools) is the best that I know of. Open Source and free. It's written in Java, but designed for integration. You can incorporate objects in the rules and rule-base applications in your components. You can even build or modify rule-bases on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

[AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced](http://search.cpan.org/~pfischer/AI-ExpertSystem-Advanced-0.03/lib/AI/ExpertSystem/Advanced.pm) or [AI::ExpertSystem::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~peterhi/AI-ExpertSystem-Simple.1.2/lib/AI/ExpertSystem/Simple.pm)  is a Perl solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try JESS, but it is Java-based. Amzilogic also provide a good platform.