# Are there open source expert systems with reasoning capabilities?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, expert-system

For learning purposes I'd like to study an open source expert system, in particular one that can reason and explain it's reasoning. Which ones do you know?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open source expert system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369566/open-source-expert-system)

Comment: Not a possible duplicate at all. The linked question is specific to C#.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Some open source expert systems / expert systems tools (tools you can use to write Expert Systems) include

- [C Language Integrated Production System (CLIPS)](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/), CLIPS is an enviroment used to make rule or o bject based expert systems
- [Python Knowledge Engine Pyke](http://pyke.sourceforge.net/index.html), Pyke allows you to use Logic Programming to make expert systems in Python
- [OpenExpert](http://law-expert.sourceforge.net/) PHP Expert System Tool mainly focused on application for Legal Expert Systems.
- [d3web](http://www.d3web.de/) is Java Knowledge Base  System that uses XML
- [jColibri](http://gaia.fdi.ucm.es/research/colibri/jcolibri) Reference Platform for Case Base Reasoning Programs in Java
- [DTRules](http://dtrules.com/wiki2/index.php?title=Main_Page)  Decision Table based rules engine in Java
- [drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools) is a well supported Java based rule-processing engine
- [Euler](http://www.agfa.com/w3c/euler/)Euler is an inference engine supporting logic based proofs.
- [Infosapient](http://info-sapient.sourceforge.net/) Java Business Rules Engine
- [Jena](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/) Jena is a Java framework which includes a rule-based inference engine, a ontology API f and a query engine
- [JEOps](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~jeops/)  JEOPS adds forward chaining, first-order production rules to Java in order facilitate expert systems development using declarative programming
- [JLisa](http://jlisa.sourceforge.net/) A CLips like rule engine with a Common Lisp interface in Java
- [mandarax](http://code.google.com/p/mandarax/) A derivation rule compiler for Java
- [ofBiz](http://ofbiz.apache.org/) Java based Business Rules Engine
- [OpenCyc](http://www.opencyc.org/)OpenCyc is the open source version of the Cyc technology, the world's largest and most complete general knowledge base and commonsense reasoning engine.
- [DEX](http://kt.ijs.si/MarkoBohanec/dex.html) DEX is an interactive computer program for the development of qualitative multi-attribute decision models and the evaluation of options

Additional relevant resources can be found in the list [here](http://aaai.org/AITopics/Software#open).

In terms of recommendations at which Expert Systems to look at for learning purposes, I would recommend OpenCyC. There is very intereting Google Tech Talk [Computers vs Common Sense](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAtn-4fhuWA)  about the Cyc technology.

Without additional information and clarification it is difficult to make further recommendations.

Comment: Here is a working link for the [Computers versus Common Sense talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAtn-4fhuWA)