# CLIPS command line prompt for Mac

Tags: nlp, clips

I have downloaded the dmg file for CLIPS, the rule based language system due to NASA. But I am not able to find any executable that lets me run the command prompt version of CLIPS on mac. I have thoroughly checked all the folders and have googled to no end.

Also, is there any other more modern rule engine out there that is worth looking at? We are trying to write language rules for phrase chunking and entity relation extraction in incomplete phrase like sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've uploaded a zip file, clips_mac_osx_executables_630.zip, to https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/6.30/ that includes both the IDE and the Console applications. Alternately you can download Xcode from the Mac App Store and the Mac CLIPS projects from SourceForge and build the console application.

There are a number of open source expert system tools: [Are there open source expert systems with reasoning capabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642004/are-there-open-source-expert-systems-with-reasoning-capabilities/9643330#9643330). Questions asking for recommendations are likely to be marked as a duplicate or off-topic and closed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the revert. I am able to use the console now. I will keep the caveat about recommendation questions in mind for next time.